# Why does SQOOP launch 4 mappers by default?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, mapper

I am just trying to understand why by default SQOOP launches 4 mappers? In some cases if we raise the mappers to 8, there are chances that could give us better performance. So, what criteria has been considered for choosing the default mappers as 4 ?  Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I will quote [7.2.4.Controlling Parallelism](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_parallelism) from Apache Sqoop's official site.

By default, four tasks are used. Some databases may see improved performance by increasing this value to 8 or 16.

> ***Do not increase the degree of parallelism greater than that available within your MapReduce cluster; tasks will run serially and will likely increase the amount of time required to perform the import.***

Likewise,

> **Do not increase the degree of parallelism higher than that which your database can reasonably support. Connecting 100 concurrent
> clients to your database may increase the load on the database server
> to a point where performance suffers as a result.**

So your answer is `Performance Issues.` To achieve a better performance under normal conditions, this value was decided to be named as default. Hope that helps.